# How to use user-provided variables with ExifTool?

Tags: exiftool

I would like to rename my photos using `exiftool`. This is my desired folder structure:

```
YYYY/
  MM/
    EVENT/
      YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.ext
```

Here is an example script for what I would like to do:

```
echo 'Name of event?'
read event
exiftool -r '-FileName<CreateDate' -d '%Y/%m/%event/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le' .
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. How can I incorporate the name of the event in my folder structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't using the variable with the user-provided input correctly. This answer assumes you're trying to run this script using a `bash` (or compatible) shell. If not, you'll need to refer to how to handle variables within your shell.

You need to reference the shell variable using the syntax of the shell, not the `exiftool` argument, and remove the single ("strong") quotes, which cause the variable reference to be a mere literal string (passing the name, not the value, to `exiftool`). What you actually want is:

```
event="EVENT"
exiftool -r '-FileName<CreateDate' -d "%Y/%m/$event/%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%le" .
```

The double ("weak") quotes will allow the correctly-referenced variable (using "$" as a prefix) to be substituted by the shell, while still protecting any whitespace in the user input.